# How to use Ternary condition inside a Ternaroy Operator in xml while setting data to a TextView with android databinding

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, viewmodel

```
 <TextView
    android:text="@{viewModel.sample.length>0?"first":"sorry"}"
    ---/>
```

above xml code is for set Text only for following condition below,

```
if(sample.length>0){
  textId.setText("first")
}else{
  textId.setTex("sorry")
}
```

but,How  can i handle in xml for the following condition below?

```
if(sample.length>0){
      textId.setText("first")
    }else if(sample.length>5){
      textId.setTex("second")
    }else{
      textId.setTex("sorry")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can use ternary condition inside another Ternary operator as well.

You can use Ternary Operator like this :-

```
   <TextView
        android:text="@{viewModel.sample.length>5 ? "second" : viewModel.sample.length>0?"first":"sorry"}"
        ----/>
```

Comment: upvote my question @Thunder,  it will help more people to visible

Answer (score 0):

Try Nested ternary operator like

```
<TextView
    android:text="@{viewModel.sample.length>0?(@{viewModel.sample.length>5?"second":"first"):"sorry"}"
    --------------------------------/>
```